# JQuery insert calculated value into a form text field

Tags: jquery

I have a form below

```
<form id="credit-card-submission-form-1" class="visual-form-builder vfb-form-1 " method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

and I have this following field within the `<form` tag.

```
<input
type="text" name="vfb-17" id="vfb-17" value="" class="vfb-text  vfb-medium  required  " />
```

I want to take input value from this field below, lets say if `400` was entered from `id="vfb-15` field, I want to take the `400` and apply `3.25%` to this field `id="vfb-17"`.

```
<input
type="text" name="vfb-15" id="vfb-15" value="" class="vfb-text  vfb-medium  required  " />
```

**This is what I have tried so far just to test out if I can access the field:**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
     $('#vfb-17').val( $('#vfb-17').val() + 'My new text' )
});
    </script>
```

I can't get this value/'My new text' even inserted into the field in the above JQuery.

**@Anuj Khandelwal** / 
 thank you for your answer. I modified your code to fit my form and below is the **JQuery** modification I've made to make my form work properly:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
$('#vfb-15').keyup(function(){
   var vfbVal = $(this).val();
   var vfb15Val = (vfbVal*3.5)/100;
   $('#vfb-17').val(vfb15Val);
 });
});
</script>
```

Here is the final edit to the working code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $('#vfb-15').keyup(function(){
       var vfbVal = $(this).val().replace("$", "");
       var vfb15Val = (vfbVal*3.5)/100;
       $('#vfb-17').val(vfb15Val);
       var total = parseInt(vfbVal)+parseInt(vfb15Val);
       console.log(total);
       $('#vfb-18').val(total);
     });
    });
    </script>
```

Comment: You need to be more clear as to what your goal is. Type a number into `vfb-17` and then display that value * .325 inside `vfb-15`?

Comment: @theblindprophet its the other way around, I'm editing my question. ty.

Comment: @theblindprophet sorry for the question being confusing, it's a form within a cms, I was trying to figure out how to put it therefore it's visually readable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this :

```
$('#vfb-17').keyup(function(){
  var vfbVal = $(this).val();
  var vfb15Val = (vfbVal*3.5)/100;
  $('#vfb-15').val(vfb15Val+'My new text');
});
```

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/webdevanuj/6rw9sLf3/)

Answer (score 0):

See answer here:
https://jsfiddle.net/wz2jn5sn/

You need to get the value properly, then calculate and assign to the new field.
HTML:

```
   <form id="credit-card-submission-form-1" class="visual-form-builder vfb-form-1 " method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    VFB17: <input
type="text" name="vfb-17" id="vfb-17" value="" class="vfb-text  vfb-medium  required  " />
    VFB15: <input
type="text" name="vfb-15" id="vfb-15" value="" class="vfb-text  vfb-medium  required  " />
    <input type="button" class="calc" value="Calculate"/>
    </form>
```

JAVASCRIPT:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
 $('.calc').on("click", function(){
 var newVal=$('#vfb-15').val() * .0325;
 $('#vfb-17').val(newVal);
});
 ( $('#vfb-17').val() + 'My new text' )
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this -

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/oaerqgs0/9/)

HTML CODE

```
<form id="credit-card-submission-form-1" class="visual-form-builder vfb-form-1 " method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <input type="text" name="vfb-17" id="vfb-17" value="" class="vfb-text  vfb-medium  required">
  <input type="text" name="vfb-15" id="vfb-15" value="" class="vfb-text  vfb-medium  required">
</form>
```

JAVASCRIPT CODE

```
$('input[name=vfb-15]').blur(function(){
    $('input[name=vfb-17]').val($(this).val()*.0325);
});
```